# column to matrix VBA

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, range

I need to reformat a single column (range) of 100+ thousand integers to a user defined matrix of rows and columns. All my online searches have been disappointing in that they're too complicated or not exactly what I need.  Index and Offsets won't due because the matrix dimensions (300+ cols, 300+ rows) would be prohibitive for copying over and down.  A function would be sufficient that includes the range index, num_cols, num_rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you mention 100,000+ integers, fitting into 90,000+ cells of a 2D matrix. that would mean that, on the average, only a few integers would be in any given matrix cell. ... what decides which integer goes into which cell?

Comment: So you are saying if your column contained 1,6,2, 7, 9,12 and the user asked for 2 by 3 you want a matrix whose first row is 1, 6, 2 and whose second row is 7, 9 ,12? So your function would get told where your column starts and go down it and move the values (but preferably not one at a time?) into your new matrix?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming I understand your question (and if not I will withdraw this answer, just let me know), the following entered as an array formula in the spot you want your answer to land should work. InputCol would be where the data now sit. I am not checking sizes and such. You may soup it up to do that. If this is indeed what you want, someone can probably make it do a little better by copying a row (using Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose) at a time (though I suspect that gets into offset and less readability).

```
Function SoTest(ByRef inputCol As range, NumRows As Long, NumCols As Long) As Variant
    Dim NewMatrix() As Variant
    Dim i, j, k As Long
    ReDim NewMatrix(1 To NumRows, 1 To NumCols)
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To NumRows
     For j = 1 To NumCols
       NewMatrix(i, j) = inputCol(k, 1)
       k = k + 1
     Next j
    Next i
    SoTest = NewMatrix
End Function
```

Comment: I think that will work. My VBA stinks, so if you'll indulge me, how do I write SoTest to a new range of cells?  Thanks so much.

Comment: I have coded a variant which writes the result to a new range, but I'm getting NAME errors on both versions?  Probably doing something very stupid and newbie.

Comment: Do not beat yourself up. People learn by making mistakes. I did just 12 entries in column A starting at row 1 and made it a 4 by 3. What worked for me was to select a range of cells the right size for the matrix. Then just once enter =SoTest(A1:A12,4,3) and hit <Ctrl><Shift><Enter> [if you do that right curly braces should show up around your formula].I suggest just copy my function in first (use <alt><fn><f11> to bring up the vb window) and try it. Then tinker as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I really appreciate it.